# Is it useful to have a word limit on comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we allow more space and possibly a larger font for comments?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/can-we-allow-more-space-and-possibly-a-larger-font-for-comments)

I was asking myself... Very often comments to questions/answers are used to in-depth analyze claims and conclusions brought upon in original posts. As such, it can become difficult to express one's thoughts in the small space provided by comments, and it can become frustrating to see a red "Word Limit Exceeded" warning when one would have so much more to say.

As to promote discussion and engage users, would it be useful to consider extending or removing word limit on comments? Maybe it could be implemented as some kind of privilege, available only to users with a certain reputation...

Comment: The simple answer is that we don't *want* to promote discussion in the comments. They might be useful for that purpose, but that's merely a side effect of their intended purpose, which is **strictly for clarification**. If you want to engage in an extended, potentially enlightening discussion about philosophy, then **please post a new question**. The user you'd ordinarily correspond with in a comment thread could post a much more well-developed answer to your new question, as could anyone else who knew about the topic.

Comment: (I'm against pushing this to chat though; if it's philosophical in nature, and possibly interesting to other users, then it belongs on the site as a new question.)

Answer (score 0):

You are of course not prevented from contributing two comments in a row (you will sometimes see people use "(cont'd.)" to mark the second half of a two-part comment.)

But keep in mind there is a reason for the limit -- comments are (generally speaking) not nearly as constructive or useful as well-formulated questions and answers.

In other words, comments are [**not** the place for extended discussion.](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/not-in-comments-please-how-to-handle-interesting-discussions) I would encourage you to please use the chat for longer conversations and debates.